# Using ido completion for selecting a repository for magit

Tags: helm, magit, ido, completing-read

I like to use `ido` for completing file paths and `helm` for all other things. I have tried setting `magit-completing-read-function` to `magit-ido-completing-read`. This doesn't change `magit-status` behaviour which calls `read-directory-name`. Here is what I have set for `ido` and `helm`:

```
(use-package ido
  :doc "I like `ido' for file paths' completion. Currently, the
  vector syntax [remap ..] is broken and using strings there is a
  workaround: https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/issues/166"
  :ensure t
  :bind (("<remap> <read-file-name>" . ido-read-file-name)
         ("<remap> <read-directory-name>" . ido-read-directory-name))
  :config
  (ido-mode 1)
  (setq ido-enable-flex-matching t
        ido-auto-merge-work-directories-length -1
        ido-save-directory-list-file (expand-file-name "ido.last"
                                                       temp-files-directory)
        ido-ignore-buffers '("\\` "  "^#.*" ".*freenode\.net.*"
                             ".*irc\.slack\.com.*" "\\*helm.*")
        ido-decorations '("\n-> " "" "\n   " "\n   ..." "[" "]" " [No match]"
                          " [Matched]" " [Not readable]" " [Too big]"
                          " [Confirm]")))

(use-package helm
  :doc "Helm for everything except file paths."
  :ensure t
  :diminish helm-mode
  :bind (("M-x" . helm-M-x)
         ("M-y" . helm-show-kill-ring)
         ("C-. C-r" . helm-grep-it))

  :config
  (helm-mode 1)

  ;; For some reason, this doesn't work. For example, `magit-status'
  ;; always uses `helm' for `read-file-name'.
  (add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist
               '(find-file . ido))
  (add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist
               '(dired . ido))
  (add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist
               '(read-file-name . ido-read-file-name)))
```

Comment: [ido-ubiquitous](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-ubiquitous)?

Comment: By the way, your `<remap>`s don't do anything because `read-file-name` and `read-directory-name` are not interactive commands so they can't have any bindings.

Comment: No, I don't want to use `ido-ubiquitous` as I have mentioned. I am using `helm` for most of the things and `ido` only for files and directories.

Answer (score 2):

Magit only used `magit-completing-read` when reading "magit-specific" things. When reading things that other packages also need to read, then it uses the specialized functions provided by Emacs instead. For files and directories the work is ultimately done by `read-file-name-default`.

> I like to use `ido` for completing file paths and `helm` for all other things.

So this doesn't really have anything to do with Magit. Unless you meant "use `ido` for completing file paths if and only if that is needed by Magit", which the following suggests:

> I have tried setting `magit-completing-read-function` to `magit-ido-completing-read`.

However, I don't think that it would make sense for Magit to support reading file/directory names using a framework different from what every other package uses. I assume nearly everyone would want to use the same mechanism for reading files across all of Emacs. So if you meant that, then you are out of luck.

Using a different completion mechanism for files (regardless of what packages needs the user to select a file) than for anything else does make some sense though.

That appears to be supported. From `helm-completing-read-handlers-alist`'s doc-string:

```
Ido is also supported, you can use `ido-completing-read' and
`ido-read-file-name' as value of an entry or just 'ido.
...
Note that you don't need to enable `ido-mode' for this to work.
```

Comment: If you see carefully, I have already set `helm-completing-read-handers-alist`. It doesn't work as has been written in the documentation. And if I do not enable `ido-mode`, I don't get `ido-completing-read` for file paths. That is all I want -- Ido for file paths and helm for everything else, e.g. `describe-symbol`

Comment: I overlooked that, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found the solution to my problem. `magit-status` ultimately calls `read-file-name`. The `read-file-name` function uses `read-file-name-function` variable to find the function that it can call for reading a file path. `helm-mode` sets it to `helm--generic-read..` and it doesn't respect the value of `helm-completing-read-handlers` for me somehow.

The only way I could make it use `ido` was with:

```
(setq read-file-name-function 'ido-read-file)
```

Comment: You should probably open a bug report against `helm`.

Comment: You may be able to use `let` to make that setting temporary.